# Choosing a networking protocol

Tags: mbed, networking

I need several mbeds to communicate with a host PC, which will issue commands to individual mbeds. What would be a suitable networking protocol to achieve this? Bear in mind, an internet connection is not required, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Which type of mbed? There are multiple.

Comment: The popular and small LPC1768 dev board. I'm thinking of using UDP because of its simplicity, relative to TCP. Would this be appropriate when considering motors will be controlled by the mbeds?

Comment: What's wrong with TCP? The code is already out there.

Comment: Depending on the use case TCP may have too much overhead. MQTT has gained popularity lately in home automation because of small packets, small memory requirements, and somewhat configurable levels of fault tolerance/correction. Might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it seems you are considering UDP.

There is nothing wrong with that choice for a local Ethernet network. You can implement any reliability you need within your software.

How much of the stack you need will depend and you have given almost no information:

1. What Mbed OS version?
2. IpV4/6/6LowPan?
3. Ethernet switched environment or point-to-point passthrough?
4. DHCP or fixed IP addresses (IPv4 or 6)
5. Packet rate, packet size?